# Objective-C replace a property at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Can I replace an property with new one using some obj-c runtime features.

So I have a class A which contains a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Status *status;
```

So I want to inherit from this class like `ClassB : ClassA` and have ability to switch original `@property (nonatomic, strong) Status *status;` to my new property like `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger status;`

So the reasone why I needed because I don't want to have a full copy of class A which contains 20 properties, so I just want to inherit from it and replace one with needed type.

Not sure if this possible, but I know something like swizzling and some obj-c runtime features can make a magic in the code.

Comment: This would violate the Liskov substitution principle http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567768/Object-Oriented-Design-Principles

Comment: @Paulw11, yep you are right)